# Is there any straightforward way to populate and update a Realm-Xamarin from JSON?

Tags: xamarin, realm

I'm trying to port an Android app with a Realm to Xamarin so it'll be also available for iOS devices. In Android, I have several JSON files with some necessary initial data, e.g. **cities.json**, and I import it at the beginning with `realm.createOrUpdateAllFromJson(Class<E> clazz, InputStream in)` method, like this:

```
private void loadInitialCities(Realm realm) {
    InputStream stream = context.getAssets().open("data/cities.json");
    realm.createOrUpdateAllFromJson(City.class, stream);
}
```

I also find this method very useful when retrieving data from a web service in form of JSON.

Now with Xamarin I don't see any equivalent to such method. Is there any method to achieve this? Or at least a workaround/tool to create a RealmObject from a JSON in C#?

Comment: Looks like an open issue: https://github.com/realm/realm-dotnet/issues/702

Answer (score 2):

I wrote my own extension methods for doing this (yes, I miss the built-in helper methods also).

- https://github.com/sushihangover/Realm.Json.Extensions

Here is a basic example of how I do it:

**JSON Model:**

```
[
    {
        "name": "Alabama",
        "abbreviation": "AL"
    },
    {
        "name": "Alaska",
        "abbreviation": "AK"
    },
    ~~~~
]
```

**Realm Model:**

```
public class State : RealmObject
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string abbreviation { get; set; }
}
```

**`Xamarin.Android` asset and `Newtonsoft` Streaming reader:**

```
var config = RealmConfiguration.DefaultConfiguration;
config.SchemaVersion = 1;
using (var theRealm = Realm.GetInstance("StackOverflow.realm"))
using (var assetStream = Assets.Open("States.json"))
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(assetStream))
using (var jsonTextReader = new JsonTextReader(streamReader))
{
    var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
    if (!jsonTextReader.Read() || jsonTextReader.TokenType != JsonToken.StartArray)
        throw new Exception("Bad Json, start of array missing");
    while (jsonTextReader.Read())
    {
        if (jsonTextReader.TokenType == JsonToken.EndArray)
            break;
        var state = serializer.Deserialize<State>(jsonTextReader);
        theRealm.Write(() =>
        {
            var realmState = theRealm.CreateObject<State>();
            realmState.abbreviation = state.abbreviation;
            realmState.name = state.name;
        });
    }
}
```

#### Update: One of my extensions methods:

**Extension Method Usage:**

```
using (var theRealm = Realm.GetInstance("StackOverflow.realm"))
using (var assetStream = Assets.Open("States.json"))
{
    theRealm.JsonArrayToRealm<State>(assetStream);
}
```

**Extension Method:**

`Note`: This uses `AutoMapper` to copy `RealmObject` and avoid reflection, also using `Newtonsoft.Json`.

```
public static class RealmDoesJson
{
    public static void JsonArrayToRealm<T>(this Realm realm, Stream stream) where T : RealmObject
    {
        Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<T, T>();
        });
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(stream))
        using (var jsonTextReader = new JsonTextReader(streamReader))
        {
            var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
            if (!jsonTextReader.Read() || jsonTextReader.TokenType != JsonToken.StartArray)
                throw new Exception("MALFORMED JSON, Start of Array missing");
            while (jsonTextReader.Read())
            {
                if (jsonTextReader.TokenType == JsonToken.EndArray)
                    break;
                var jsonObject = serializer.Deserialize<T>(jsonTextReader);
                realm.Write(() => // inside while loop / single object transaction for memory manangement reasons...
                {
                    var realmObject = realm.CreateObject(typeof(T).Name);
                    Mapper.Map<T, T>(jsonObject, realmObject);
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like a look solution, I will try it ASAP

Comment: Starting with [0.80.0](https://github.com/realm/realm-dotnet/releases/tag/0.80.0), `Realm.Manage` is massively faster, so swapping `Mapper.Map` for `Realm.Manage(jsonObject)` should yield a nice performance boost - you can check the [Github thread](https://github.com/realm/realm-dotnet/issues/702#issuecomment-256692412) for more details.